# Really Simple Captcha Wordpress not validating

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code on my page.

```
<?php 
$captcha_instance = new ReallySimpleCaptcha();
    $captcha_instance->bg = array( 238, 238, 238 );
    $word = $captcha_instance->generate_random_word();
    $prefix = mt_rand();
    $captcha_img = $captcha_instance->generate_image( $prefix, $word );
    $captcha = plugins_url( '/really-simple-captcha/tmp/').$captcha_img;
    $response = $_POST['response'];
    $correct = $captcha_instance->check($prefix,$response);
    var_dump($correct);
?>
<div id="main-container">
    <?php if ( $pages->have_posts() ) while ( $pages->have_posts() ) : $pages->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="page_overlay" style="display:none;"></div>  
        <div id="form-container">
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo the_permalink();?>">
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" >
                <img src="<?php echo $captcha; ?>" alt="captcha"/>
                <input type="text" id="response" name="response" >
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            </form>

        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

When i try to enter the wrong captcha image it still sends the form, I displayed the variable that handles the checking and its keeps on returning "FALSE" value even if the captcha image is correct. $correct variable always return false;

Comment: not familiar with this plugin, but shouldn't you check $response against previous $prefix, stored from session for example. This way you check $response against new generated captcha.

Comment: I also had some troubles with ReallySimpleCaptcha, so I'm now using [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) without any problems...

Answer (score 0):

I solved by replacing (in **simple-contact-save.php**) the line

```
if( $_SESSION['security_code'] == mysql_real_escape_string(trim($gcf_captcha)) && !empty($_SESSION['security_code'] ) )
```

with

```
if( $_SESSION['security_code'] == trim($gcf_captcha) && !empty($_SESSION['security_code'] ) )
```

It seems that the (deprecated) function ***mysql_real_escape_string*** doesn't like UTF-8 character encoding and makes the comparison fail.